# Acceso a B.D de Firestore sincronamente

Tags: android

Necesito un ejemplo de como hacer un acceso a la base de dato de firestore de forma sincrona, necesito si o si que se ejecute esta orden y que devuelva lo que se le pida y despues siga ejecutando las siguientes sentencias.

Ya se que esto se ejecuta asincronamente pero necesito hacerlo sincrona.

Muchas gracias, si puede ser me podeis hacer un ejemplo con la sentencia que os he mandado.

```
mfirestoreTurnos.collection("Aulas").whereEqualTo("idturno", idturno)
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        // ...
                                               
                });
```

Comment: No funciona como tú crees. Esas llamadas son asíncronas porque de otro modo bloquearían el hilo principal, la consecuencia sería una App pésima que los usuarios terminarían abandonando. Lo propio sería que desde dentro del `onComplete` llames a otro método que haga lo siguiente que haya que hacer, no re-inventar la rueda para crear un código totalmente contrario al paradigma.

Comment: Hacerlo sincrónicamente no es lo ideal-